# Can a Asp.Net chart be displayed on the home page?

Tags: asp.net, charts, data-visualization

I am currently experimenting with Asp.Net's built in Data Visualization stuff.

I set up my first chart (VS 2017/framework 4.7) but ran into problems with an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error.

This was at the top of my stacktrace:

```
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.GetHandlerUrl()
```

After Googling the issue, I came across a post which suggested that the page url that was at fault. This turned out to be true.

This works: **mysite.com/about**

This doesn't work: **mysite.com**

Effectively charting sees the home page as "", which is when the error occurs - so you can't use a chart on a home page.

This sounds wrong but I've tested it myself and it is an issue. The post offered no alternative solutions other than not to use a chart on the home page.

Anyone come across this issue and found an alternative solution?

Comment: Can you please provide your code? It seems that you have not write the code for index method properly OR there is some issue in routing file.